# Recompiled PHP, now Apache not parsing PHP files

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I recompiled PHP earlier today, now when you access PHP pages in a browser, Apache displays its source code instead of parsing it. Do I need to reset some configuration or recompile Apache?

This is on Centos 5.5 with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.17

Comment: How is this off topic?

Comment: Guess you're right. How can it be migrated?

Comment: It just needs to be voted there a few more times, wait and see.

Comment: I'm not sure serverfault really wants the 504th duplicate asking for basic apache and php setup instructions.

Comment: AddType application/x-httpd-php php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure your libphp.so (or libphp5.so) is in the correct place. If it got installed in a different place, you'll need to update where apache thinks it is. Depending on how you've got apache setup, there should be an IfModule block that loads the apache module. It'll look something like this:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    LoadModule php5_module    /usr/lib/php5.3/apache2/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
```

The path and module name may be different. But if that's all fine, it may be you're using an "Action" with ExecCGI, for example:

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php
Action php-cgi /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/php.cgi
```

The path to the cgi module may have changed.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line type:

> apachectl configtest

Do you get any errors?

In httpd.conf is the following line uncommented:

> LoadModule php5_module ...